# Android: Create a mirror image of a view

Tags: java, android

I wrote a code that reflects the view of an ImageView in the splash activity. In order to implement this, I took three steps.

1. Create an ImageView in the layout_splash.xml file and also in the SplashActivity.java.
2. Call the setImageBitmap method with the reflected ImageView variable
3. Declare a method that reflects the view of the image.

And here is the code.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView ivLogo;
    private SharedPreferences appPreferences;
    private Typeface typeface;
    private TextView tvAppName;
    private boolean isAppInstalled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        String appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);
        if(isAppInstalled == false) {
            Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
            shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
            editor.commit();
        }

        // Set the app name's font
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Catull.ttf");
        tvAppName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAppName);
        tvAppName.setTypeface(typeface);

        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_gruppo);
        ivLogo = new ImageView(this);
        ivLogo.setImageBitmap(getReflection(originalImage));

        Handler hd = new Handler();
        hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InitialActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Implement the animation on activity change
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);
                finish();
            }
        }, 1200);
    }

    public Bitmap getReflection(Bitmap image) {
        // The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
        final int reflectionGap = 4;

        // Get the bitmap from the mipmap folder
        Bitmap originalImage = image;

        int width = originalImage.getWidth();
        int height = originalImage.getHeight();

        // This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(1, -1);

        // Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
        // We only want the bottom half of the image
        Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
                height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

        // Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
        Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                (height + height / 2), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
        // the image plus gap plus reflection
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
        // Draw in the original image
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
        //Draw the reflection Image
        canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap, null);

        // Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
                originalImage.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
                + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
        // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
        paint.setShader(shader);
        // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
        canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
                + reflectionGap, paint);
        return bitmapWithReflection;
    }
}
```

But when running the application, I don't see the reflected image but just the plain one. Something wrong with the code?

Comment: Because the `ivLogo` didn't add into the content view anywhere, so it won't appear on screen.

Comment: Oh jesus. The problems always occur in the very small things. I just found it out and fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems always occur from the very small things. In here the problem is that the ivLogo variable was not added into the content view. So the ivLogo must be added in the onCreate method like this,

```
ivLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLogo);
```

instead of

```
ivLogo = new ImageView();
```